# Backtick in ECMASCRIPT : Unexpected Token Illegal

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, template-strings

I am writing a small test code in an ExpressJs app. The code is as follows :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var dataFile = require('./data/data.json');


app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var info = '';
  dataFile.speakers.forEach(function(item) {
    info += `<li>
      <h2>${item.name}</h2>
      <p>${item.summary}</p>
    </li>
    `;
  });
  res.send(`
    <h1>My Meetups</h1>
    ${info}
    `);
});

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

When I try to execute the command

> node app/app.js

in Git bash terminal, I get the following error :

```
> E:\expressjs\app\app.js:11
>     info += `<li>
>             ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
>     at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
>     at startup (node.js:119:16)
>     at node.js:935:3
```

What I tried :

1. Checked node version : Using node 0.10.37
2. Tried running the node command with --harmony option as suggested : Same error
3. Tried visiting the ECMA compatibility table website : Wasn't able to search the right information

Am using the Atom Editor

What I suspect : Incompatible version of Node and ECMA

Can someone help with this ?

Thanks

Comment: Template literals were introduced in most recent versions of Node.js v4, if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this site. It shows all es6 features implemented in nodeJS

http://node.green/

My suspect is that you using very old version of node(almost all features gives error in node 0.10).

Try to upgrade into node6 and all should be OK.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am trying to run another main project on the same version for testing on the computer. I fear upgrading node from such a lower version to a higher version might break things in that main project.

Comment: Well..not long time ago i upgrade from node 0.10 to node 4.4 all works good...also node 6 works as well. Off corse it's scary. But 0.10 is very old. So try node4 for start and then go to 6...

Comment: Yeah the web link you provided, actually confirms, a proper support on a nodev4 and above.

Comment: Glad that can help!